# Artnet Poll Reply packet not being acknowledged

Tags: c#, artnet

I hope someone can help me here.  I used the information available here:  https://art-net.org.uk/how-it-works/discovery-packets/artpollreply/
and created a function for sending an artnet poll reply when a request is received.
My computer's ip address in this test is 192.168.4.114.  I have confirmed that the poll packet is being received, and the code I'm posting transmits.  However the program I'm sending the discovery from (Jinx) is not populating the found devices.  I must have something formatted incorrectly.

If someone has a working poll reply sample I would love that, otherwise what's wrong with this?

```
                else if (e.Packet.OpCode == ArtNet.Enums.ArtNetOpCodes.Poll)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                byte[] packetData = {
                    0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x00, // 0-7 "Art-Net"
                    0x00, 0x21, // 8-9 OpCode (ArtPollReply)
                    192,168,4,114, //  10-13 IP ADDRESS
                    0x36, 0x19, // 14-15 Port-Address
                    0x01, 0x40, // 16-17 hi lo VersInfo
                    0x00,       // 18 NetSwitch
                    0x01,       // 19 SubSwitch
                    0x20, 0x60, // 20-21 OemHi, Lo
                    0x00,       // 22 Ubea version #
                    0x10,       // 23 Status 1 (configuration bits)
                    0x4c, 0x41, // 24-25 lo hi ESTA manufacturer code
                    // Short name 26-43 (18 bytes)
                    0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x44, 0x65, 0x76, 0x69, 0x63, 0x65, 0x20, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31,
                    // Long name 44-107(64 bytes)
                    0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x44, 0x65, 0x76, 0x69, 0x63, 0x65, 0x20, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, //says Art-Net Device
                    0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                    // Node Report 108-171 (64 bytes)
                    0x23, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x20, 0x5b, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x5d, 0x20, 0x41, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x20,
                    0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    // 127-173 NumPorts (2 bytes)
                    0x00, 0x01,
                    // 174-177 Port types (4 bytes)
                    0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00,
                    // 178-181 GoodInput (4 bytes)
                    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
                    // 182-185 GoodOutput (4 bytes)
                    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
                    // 186-189 SwIn (4 bytes)
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    // 190-193 SwOut (4 bytes)
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    // 194-196 deprecated
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    // 197-199 spare
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    // Style (1 byte)
                    0x00,
                    // MAC (6 bytes)
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
                    // BindIp (4 bytes)
                    192, 168, 4, 114,
                    // BindIndex (1 byte)
                    0x00,
                    // Status2 (1 byte)
                    0x00
                };
                UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

                client.Send(packetData, packetData.Length, e.Source.Address.ToString(), e.Source.Port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that I wasn't returning the "filler" data at the end of the packet.  Here's my final code with the following changes:

1. Filler bytes at the end.
2. marks the first port as #80 hex
3. Fills in the starting universe after computing it into the constituent parts.
4. Sends a reply packet for every supported universe (the recommended method).  Result:  I can now auto-search in xlights and my app is found and it reports the number of universes I am using.

   ```
              else if (e.Packet.OpCode == ArtNet.Enums.ArtNetOpCodes.Poll)
          {

              int settingsUniverse = DBFunctions.SettingValues.StartingUniverse;
              byte universe = (byte)(settingsUniverse & 0x000f);
              byte subnet = (byte)(((settingsUniverse - universe) >> 4) & 0xf);
              byte net = (byte)(settingsUniverse >> 8);
              int neededUniverses = ((frmInterface)Program.frmInterface).GetUniverseCount();

              byte[] ipAddressArray = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
              byte[] packetData = {
                  0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x00, // 0-7 "Art-Net"
                  0x00, 0x21, // 8-9 OpCode (ArtPollReply)
                  //  10-13 IP ADDRESS
                  ipAddressArray[0], ipAddressArray[1], ipAddressArray[2], ipAddressArray[3],
                  0x36, 0x19, // 14-15 Port-Address
                  0x01, 0x40, // 16-17 hi lo VersInfo
                  net,       // 18 NetSwitch
                  subnet,       // 19 SubSwitch
                  0x20, 0x60, // 20-21 OemHi, Lo
                  0x00,       // 22 Ubea version #
                  0x10,       // 23 Status 1 (configuration bits)
                  0x4c, 0x41, // 24-25 lo hi ESTA manufacturer code
                  // Short name 26-43 (18 bytes)
                  0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x74, 0x32, 0x54, 0x77, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x79, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //Artnet2Twinkly
                  // Long name 44-107(64 bytes)
                  0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x74, 0x32, 0x54, 0x77, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x79, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //Artnet2Twinkly
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                  // Node Report 108-171 (64 bytes)
                  0x23, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x20, 0x5b, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x5d, 0x20, 0x41, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x20,
                  0x41, 0x72, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  // 127-173 NumPorts (2 bytes)
                  0x00, 0x01,
                  // 174-177 Port types (4 bytes)
                  0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  // 178-181 GoodInput (4 bytes)
                  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
                  // 182-185 GoodOutput (4 bytes)
                  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
                  // 186-189 SwIn (4 bytes)
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  // 190-193 SwOut (4 bytes)
                  universe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  // 194-196 deprecated
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  // 197-199 spare
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  // Style (1 byte)
                  0x00,
                  // MAC (6 bytes)
                  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
                  // BindIp (4 bytes)
                  ipAddressArray[0], ipAddressArray[1], ipAddressArray[2], ipAddressArray[3],
                  // BindIndex (1 byte)
                  0x00,
                  // Status2 (1 byte)
                  0x00,
                  //filler
                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00

              };
              UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
              for (int i = 0; i < neededUniverses; i++)
              {
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                  client.Send(packetData, packetData.Length, e.Source.Address.ToString(), e.Source.Port);
                  packetData[190]++;
                  if (packetData[190] > 15)
                  {
                      packetData[190] = 0;
                      packetData[19]++;
                      if (packetData[19] > 15)
                      {
                          packetData[19] = 0;
                          packetData[18]++;
                      }
                  }
              }

          }
   ```